# sfdx Retrieve Custom object from one org to another org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, source

I do have a Custom Object Animal from an org called ORG1 and I want to retrieve from this ORG1 to another ORG2, so Is that possible to retrieve it with commands without using the package?

I am doing this:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject Animal__c -u ORG1
```

But is not the correct way, how can I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source commands [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source)

**You're very close. You just need to add a `:` in between `CustomObject` and your `objectAPIName` with the -m parameter.** Also, make sure that you're using the correct org alias name or your username.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Animal__c -u aliasOfOrg
```

---

**To troubleshoot similar issues going forward**, you can always utilize `--help`. For example, the following:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --help
```

Returns the many different examples and one shows the formatting with `:` between metadata type and actual api name when specifying a specific apex class. There's also an example in case you ever need to retrieve a couple different specific metadata records.

*To retrieve all Apex classes:*

```
  $ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
```

*To retrieve a specific Apex class:*

```
  $ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass:MyApexClass
```

*To retrieve all custom objects and Apex classes:*

```
  $ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject,ApexClass
```

*To retrieve all Apex classes and two specific profiles (one of which has a space in its name):*

```
  $ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "ApexClass, Profile:My Profile, Profile: AnotherProfile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use the new `sf` command to retrieve any custom object:

```
sf project retrieve start --metadata CustomObject:namespace__MyObjectName__c
```

Answer (score 0):

So it will be a 2 step process. Also you will not be able to use the `force:source:retrieve` if you are not using this command as part of a SFDX project.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a package.xml of what you want to retrieve. In this case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">    
    <types>
        <members>Animal__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

2. Then you can run this command `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -k package.xml -s -r . -u {userAlias}`. This will download the metadata you want and created a file called `unpackaged.zip`.
3. You can then deploy to the new org using this command `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f unpackaged.zip -w 10 -u {userAlias}`